# Jumping to various functions MIPS

Tags: if-statement, assembly, mips

So I am new to MIPS and I wanted to implement simple modulo arithmetic functions. I am unable to see why the program is not jumping according to the jump statements in the code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    .data
text_enquiry    :   .asciiz "Enter operation code (1-add, 2-subtract, 3-multiply, 4-exponentiation, 5-inversion, 6-exit): "
text_a          :   .asciiz "Enter a: "
text_b          :   .asciiz "Enter b: "
text_m          :   .asciiz "Enter m: "
text_result     :   .asciiz "Result = "
new_line        :   .asciiz "\n"

    .text
main:

    ##  t0 = code, t1 = a, t2 = b, t3 = m

    #print operation message
    la      $a0, text_enquiry
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall

    #read code
    li      $v0, 5
    syscall
    move    $t0, $v0

    #if code == 6
    beq     $t0, 6, exit
    j       rest

exit:
    li      $v0, 10
    syscall

    #else, continue procedure

    #print 'a, b, m' messages and read them
rest:
    la      $a1, text_a
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall
    li      $v0, 5
    syscall
    move    $t1, $v0

    la      $a1, text_b
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall
    li      $v0, 5
    syscall
    move    $t2, $v0

    la      $a1, text_m
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall
    li      $v0, 5
    syscall
    move    $t3, $v0
    j       mod

    ##  t0 = code, t1 = a, t2 = b, t3 = m, t4 = un-modded result, t5 = modded result, t6 = 
mod:
    beq     $t0, 1, func_add
    beq     $t0, 2, func_sub
    beq     $t0, 3, func_mul
    # beq       $t0, 4, func_exp

func_add:
    add     $t4, $t1, $t2
    div     $t4, $t3
    mfhi    $t5
    #print accordingly
    la      $a3, text_result
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall
    move    $a3, $t5
    li      $v0, 1
    syscall
    la      $a3, new_line
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall

    j       main

func_sub:
    sub     $t4, $t1, $t2
    div     $t4, $t3
    mfhi    $t5
    #print accordingly
    la      $a3, text_result
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall
    move    $a3, $t5
    li      $v0, 1
    syscall

    j       main

func_mul:
    mult    $t1, $t2
    mflo    $t4
    div     $t4, $t3
    mfhi    $t5
    #print accordingly
    la      $a3, text_result
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall
    move    $a3, $t5
    li      $v0, 1
    syscall

    j       main
```

As you can see, the code works fine when the code is '6' but doesn't work for any other code value.

Comment: Please be more specific when you say the code doesn't "work fine". You said what it doesn't do, but not what it does.

Comment: What environment do you use to run this? From the exit syscall I guess it's one of SPIM family simulators or MARS. Those can be configured in options to either simulate delayed branching (like real CPU does act) or not (simpler to understand for newcomers, but not like real MIPS CPU). Also those simulators have debugger included, so you can easily try yourself, what happens at every single instruction, stepping over them slowly, and examining all values in registers and your assumptions vs what the previous instruction really did. (I didn't bother to copy your code into simulator + try myself)

Comment: But I think the first branching should work (6 vs other value) with delayed branching off (with delayed branching "on" I'm actually not sure what happens when the delay branch contains another `j` instruction, never tried that in simulator and I'm not MIPS expert), so it's not clear what doesn't work for you. I believe the label `rest:` is reached in case of non-6 input.

Comment: @Ped7g "Processor operation is UNPREDICTABLE if a branch, jump, ERET, DERET, or WAIT instruction is placed in the delay slot of a branch or jump."

Comment: @Ped7g no, even the first branching doesn't work. It keep on printing the operation message in the main section and doesn't go into any of the other sections (like `rest`, `mod`, etc.)

Comment: @RaymondChen I want the code in the sections `rest`, `loop` , etc. to work. But I don't understand why those sections of code are not called. Only the 'main' section is executed repeatedly.

Comment: @MohitKorabu works for me, when I enter for example "3", the code continues at instructions after the `rest:` label. They just don't do what you expect (but it's not going to `main`, you are misunderstanding what is happening), but the branching is not a problem (yet, until you switch delayed branching ON, then your code is "unpredictable"). As I said, use the debugger to verify what the code does.

Comment: @MohitKorabu BTW, if you don't get it, I'm really trying to fix your biggest mistakes, namely: 1) I don't know how to debug my code 2) I think running it and checking output is enough to deem my code "correct/incorrect" 3) I guess what is happening instead of checking true state. Which lead you to blame problems on part which is sort of correct (the branch). I could probably also tell you that the text printing in the `rest` part is setting `a1` instead of `a0` with string address, but you will highly likely find that typo yourself very quickly, once you will learn how to use debugger...

Comment: so once you fix those biggest problems first, you will find programming in assembly much more friendly and convenient. While you keep on doing these big mistakes, you will stumble across on every tiny typo or bug, and you will be in trouble for days. Programming in assembly without debugger is real pain (I did \*that\*, but I didn't have chance to use debugger, because I didn't have computer, so I had to write the code on paper, and then I had only few hours per week to test it on real computer, and no time for debugging, so then I spend rest of week looking at paper and searching for bugs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am unable to see why the program is not jumping according to the jump statements in the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Your program **is** jumping according to the input.

What you are unable to see is what it really does and why your further text output fails, and you are unable to see that, because you didn't even look (in debugger, single-stepping over every instruction).

Would you take a look, you would clearly see that for example for input "3", the code will reach instruction after label `rest:`, so the branching is correct.

That code later is not doing what you expect, because it doesn't print the other helper prompts, because it is calling `syscall` with wrong arguments (the code sets `a1` with string address, instead of `a0`, and in `a0` is still the original operation-prompt address), but it is executed as planned.

Generally deciding on assembly code correctness only by checking input/output is very bad practice, as you can often have correct output "by accident", while the code is already doing also something different than planned, which may just bite you later, if you keep extending your code, or if you use different inputs.

To decide if your assembly code is correct, you should rather spend quite some time in debugger, verifying different inputs, and thinking how the code works and if really works as planned/assumed, while you were writing it - on per-instruction basis!

The final code should consist only of instructions which you know exactly what they are doing, and why they are part of the code, and why they are placed where they are. If anything works "by accident" without you truly understand it, you must fix it (either by understanding how it works, or by rewriting it in a way you understand how it works), it's still bug, even if the output is correct.

Comment: Yeah, I think I have used the wrong registers (a1 instead of a0). Now, it works as needed. Also I will try to use the debugger as much as I can. Thanks!